# Creating a separate window against each click on push button

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi, button, window

I am working on Windows GUI Application.There are 20 Push Buttons on my Window. Against each button click, I want to open up a new window for displaying some information. It can be anything which can display some information but since I am new to all this and I didn’t want to try anything complicated, I decided to go with the idea of creating a pop up window against each button click.

Now the problem that I am facing is that since there are 20 different windows, do I need to create 20 different window callback functions? Though there is only one control in the pop up window i.e. a Close sign, but even for that I need to have a CALLBACK function.

I had been trying with this but now this idea looks senseless. Is there any other option in which I can achieve the desired functionality?

Waiting for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all of the windows should behave the same way, then you can create a single [window procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632593.aspx) (what you're calling the `CALLBACK` function) that is shared by all of the pop-up windows.

Window procedures do not have to be unique to individual windows, but if multiple windows share the same window procedure, they will react *identically* to all messages that they receive.

For example:

```
// Message procedure for all pop-up windows.
LRESULT CALLBACK MyPopupWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{ 
    switch (msg)
    { 
        // handle any messages you want here in order to
        //   customize the behavior of your pop-up window
    } 
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

You specify a pointer to the `MyPopupWndProc` function when you register the window class for your pop-up windows (using the `RegisterClassEx` function), and then you pass the name of the registered window class when you call `CreateWindowEx` to create/display a pop-up window whenever one of the buttons on your main window is clicked.

Of course, if you're just wanting something simple for testing purposes, remember that you can always call the `MessageBox` function! No window procedures or class registration required.

Comment: +1 for the answer. Could there be a way like as simple as MessageBox() through which I can take input as well? (Since I don't think I can take input using MessageBox)

Comment: @Ayesha No, there's no built-in way to take input, MessageBox just displays static text. However, you can create a dialog box resource (instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26ewt5yf.aspx)), and then show that with the [`DialogBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645452.aspx) function. You still have to supply a window procedure callback function (WindowProc, although in this case its often called a DialogProc), but you don't have to create all the control windows manually because they're part of the template.